# Solve the differential equation $(z^2-2yz-y^2)p+(xy+zx)q=xy-zx$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was solving this differential equation by putting it into the subsidiary equation. I've found one solution i.e $c1=(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Help me find the other one

Answer (score 1):

$$(z^2-2yz-y^2)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} +(xy+zx)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=xy-zx$$
System of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{z^2-2yz-y^2}=\frac{dy}{xy+xz}=\frac{dz}{xy-xz}=$$
A first characteristic equation comes from the combination :
$=\frac{\alpha dx+\beta dy+\gamma dz}{\alpha(z^2-2yz-y^2)+\beta x(y+z)+\gamma (xy-xz)}$

with $\alpha=x$ , $\beta=y$ , $\gamma=z \quad\to\quad =\frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{(xz^2-2xyz-xy^2)+ (xy^2+xyz)+(xyz-xz^2)}= \frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{0}$

This implies $xdx+ydy+zdz=0 \quad\implies\quad x^2+y^2+z^2=c_1$

A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dy}{xy+xz}=\frac{dz}{xy-xz}$
$$\frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{y-z}{y+z}=\frac{1-\frac{z}{y}}{1+\frac{z}{y}}$$
The common way to solve this kind of ODE is change of function $z=yu(y)$
$$y\frac{du}{dy}+u=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$$
This is a separable ODE. Then, a few calculus leads to : 
$$z^2+2yz-y^2=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE can be implicitly expressed on various equivalent forms, for example :
$$\Phi\left((x^2+y^2+z^2) \:,\: (z^2+2yz-y^2)\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=F\left(z^2+2yz-y^2 \right)$$
$$z^2+2yz-y^2=G\left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function and $G=F^{-1}$.